# argument "t" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I am trying to create a transpose matrix in R however I do receive all the time error :

```
row1<-c(-0.14,0.12,0.02)
row2<-c(0.18,-0.23,0.05)
row3<-c(0.013,0.05,-0.063)
mat<-c(row1,row2,row3)
g<-t(matrix(mat,nrow=3))
```

> Error in t(matrix(mat, nrow = 3)) :    argument "t" is missing, with
> no default

Do you have any ideas where is the issue ?

Thanks , Matus

Comment: I don't get any error using your code

Comment: Try `rm(t)`, in case you have overwritten the function.

Comment: Perfect rm(t) worked perfectly :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
row1<-c(-0.14,0.12,0.02)
row2<-c(0.18,-0.23,0.05)
row3<-c(0.013,0.05,-0.063)
mat<-c(row1,row2,row3)
g<-base::t(matrix(mat,nrow=3))
```

it's probably a typo, a different library can render `t`'s role. you can specify by adding `base::` at the head of function